# MS SQL Server Use insert into a table with select while output to third table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

So, here is the conundrum I am trying to solve, let us say I have the following tables, scripted as create statements

```
create table table1 (pk int identity(1,1) primary key, a int, b int)
create table table2 (pk int identity(100,1) primary key, a int, b int)
create table tbllink (tbl1pk int, tbl2pk int)
```

now, due to some requirements oversight, I now find myself in a situation where I need to take some of the records from table1, insert them into table2 after performing some kind of ad hoc calculation, and I need to be able to link them back to each other via the bridge tbllink.

This is fairly easy to do with a cursor, see below for cursor pseudo

```
cursor for select pk, a, b from table1 where (some clause)
fetch cursor into @pk, @a, @b
while @@fetch_status
begin
insert into table2 (a, b)
    output @pk, inserted.pk into tbllink
values (@a, @b + 5)
fetch cursor into @pk, @a, @b
end
```

This works and gets me exactly the results I need, but what I would really like to be able to do is something like this.

```
insert into table2 (a, b)
   output table1.pk, inserted.pk into tbllink
select a, b + 5 from table1 where (some clause)
```

this doesn't compile, though.  Is there any way to accomplish this, or should I just use the cursor?  Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a cursor for a one-off job. I'd only worry about avoiding the cursor if you were going to build it into the system for all new inserts going forward.

Comment: You have it close.  MERGE into tbl1 output into temp table, insert into table2 with additional calcs, then link in tbllink.  a regular insert won't return the newly created identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to use the `MERGE` statement to do this:

```
-- Setup
    create table #table1 (pk int identity(1,1) primary key, a int, b int)
    create table #table2 (pk int identity(100,1) primary key, a int, b int)
    create table #tbllink (tbl1pk int, tbl2pk int)
    INSERT INTO #table1 (a,b) VALUES (1,2)

-- Load
    MERGE INTO #Table2 t USING (SELECT pk, a, b from #Table1) s ON 1 = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
      (
        a,
        b
      )
    VALUES 
      (
        a,
        b
      )
    OUTPUT s.PK, inserted.PK
    INTO #TblLink (Tbl1pk, Tbl2pk);

-- Verify
    SELECT * FROM #table1
    SELECT * FROM #table2
    SELECT * FROM #tbllink

-- Clean up
    DROP TABLE #table1
    DROP TABLE #table2
    DROP TABLE #tbllink
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful